# SPOJ Prime Generator My python code is giving a Runtime Error NZEC, why?

Tags: python

SPOJ Prime Generator My python code is giving a Runtime Error NZEC, why?

```
testcases = raw_input(" ")

def isPrime(n):
    result = True
    if n != 0 and n != 1 and n % 2 != 0 and n % 5 != 0 and n % 7 != 0 and n % 9 != 0:
        if n > 9:
            for i in range(11,n):
                if isPrime(i):
                    if n % i == 0:
                        result = False
            return result
        else:
            return result
    else:
        return False

for count in range(0,testcases):
    m,n = raw_input(" ").split()
    m = int(m)
    n = int(n)
    for i in range(m,n+1):
        if isPrime(i):
            print i
```

Comment: please edit the code of your question question, select the code and press ctrl+k then save.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a NZEC because of extra white spaces in the input. It's not difficult to design your code to handle such cases. Take the input at once and tokenize it by white spaces. See how I have done it.

```
def isPrime(n):
    result = True
    if n != 0 and n != 1 and n % 2 != 0 and n % 5 != 0 and n % 7 != 0 and n % 9 != 0:
        if n > 9:
            for i in range(11,n):
                if isPrime(i):
                    if n % i == 0:
                        result = False
            return result
        else:
            return result
    else:
        return False

def main():    # Don't leave the code in the global namespace, it runs slower
    import sys
    tokenizedInput = map(int, sys.stdin.read().split())    # Read at once, tokenize
    testcases = tokenizedInput[0]
    readAt = 1    # Position to begin reading
    for count in range(0,testcases):
        m,n = tokenizedInput[readAt:readAt+2]    # Read the tokenized input
        for i in range(m,n+1):
            if isPrime(i):
                print i
        print    # You need to separate two outputs by a line
        readAt = readAt + 2

main()
```

This will get you rid of the NZEC. However, your algorithm is both inefficient and incorrect. For the sample input test case of

```
2
1 10
3 5
```

Your modified code now outputs

```
3

3
```

The expected output

```
2
3
5
7

3
5
```

Answer (score 0):

For every number `>= 11` you are recursively calling `isPrime`. If the number is large enough an stack overflow error will occur.

The Prime Generator problem on SPOJ has a large number limit. Try running your program with large numbers, like `999900000 1000000000`.